# How can I instantly move the active window to a secondary monitor in openbox?

Tags: multiple-monitors, window, openbox

By looking at http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration I have figured out a few things about modifying the behavior of openbox. My config lives in `~/.config/openbox/conf.xml`.

I know that I can use the `SendToDesktop` action to send the active window to a different virtual desktop using for example the `window + down arrow` keys by setting the following config:

```
<keybind key="W-down">
  <action name="SendToDesktop">
    <to>"south"</to>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Furthermore I know that I can move the active window around on the current virtual desktop using the `window + arrow` keys by setting the following config:

```
<keybind key="Super_L">
  <action name="Move"/>
</keybind>
```

The latter would allow me to slowly move the window to the adjacent secondary monitor. I am hoping for a way to move the active window to the adjacent monitor (not virtual desktop) instantly. Can it be done? If not, is there a way to make the window move faster when moving it using the arrow keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your looking for the `MoveResizeTo` action:

```
<keybind key="W-2">
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <!-- move the window to the second monitor -->
    <monitor>2</monitor>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

You can also supply `<x>` and `<y>` options to absolute position the window on the moved to monitor:

```
<keybind key="W-c">
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <!-- center the window on the first monitor -->
    <x>center</x>
    <y>center</y>
    <monitor>1</monitor>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Source: [OpenBox Actions Documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#MoveResizeTo)